# geolocation ionic working in browser test but not on android

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, geolocation

I'm writing an app which needs to get your location at a certain point.
I used the ionic native geolocation for this which is send to the google API for reverse geocoding.

It works completely like I want it to when I just use [`ionic serve`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjwKn.png).
But when I try to run it on android it doesn't seem to work at all.

if I run `ionic cordova run android --device -c -l` I get these console logs:

`[20:23:58]  console.log: Device Ready
 [20:23:58]  console.log: [object Object]
 [20:23:58]  console.log: No location Error`

this is the snippet of code at that page.

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private geo: Geolocation, private platform: Platform, public geocodeProvider: GeocodeProvider) {
      this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
        console.log("Device Ready");
        this.geo.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then(resp =>{
            console.log(resp.coords.latitude);
            console.log(resp.coords.longitude);
            this.getCountry(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        });
      });
  }
  
  getCountry(lat,long){
    this.geocodeProvider.getCountry(lat,long).subscribe(result =>this.country = this.getName(result));
  }

  
  
  getName(JSON:IRootObject){
      var location = JSON.results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
      return JSON.results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
  }
```

I can't seem to find out why it isn't working.

EDIT:

My android manifest:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="***" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>`

Comment: are you having the needed permissions? `COURSE_LOCATION`, `FINE_LOCATION` ?

Comment: I edited my question with the android manifest

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on Android 6 or above. There you have to request permissions at runtime.

Install:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/android-permissions
```

Use:

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';


constructor(private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) { 
    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.LOCATION_COURSE)
     .then(
       result => console.log('Has permission?', result.hasPermission),
       err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.LOCATION_COURSE)
     );
}
```

You have to do this request for each permission you need.

See https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/ for details.

In the Guidelines by Google you find additional infos how to request permissions and handle the user response (explain why you need the permissions, don't ask to much, ...)

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Is this something that changed recently? We are experience some users reporting that geolocation stopped working 3 weeks ago on android devices. (it works on IOS). @fastr.de  (I am not using ionic, just cordova and wonder if I can do something similar)

Comment: ionic uses https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions to request permissions. But the permission request method was introduced in Android 6, that is way older then 3 weeks ;-/

Answer (score 0):

@fastr.de I added this:

```js
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private geo: Geolocation, private platform: Platform, public geocodeProvider: GeocodeProvider,private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) {
    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).then(
        result => console.log('Has permission? ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION',result.hasPermission),
        err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
      );  
      this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS).then(
        result => console.log('Has permission? ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS',result.hasPermission),
        err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS)
      ); 
      this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then(
        result => console.log('Has permission? ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION',result.hasPermission),
        err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
      ); 
      
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
        console.log("Device Ready");
        this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS]);
        this.geo.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then(resp =>{
            
            console.log(resp.coords.latitude);
            console.log(resp.coords.longitude);
            this.getCountry(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        });
        
        
      });

    
  }
```

and the console output is:

```
[16:17:15]  console.log: Device Ready
[16:17:15]  console.log: Has permission? ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS true
[16:17:15]  console.log: Has permission? ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION true
[16:17:15]  console.log: Has permission? ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION true
[16:17:15]  console.log: [object Object]
[16:17:15]  console.log: No location Error
```